# How to override Model defaults method of 3rd party installed app, django?

Tags: python, django, model, overriding

I just installed [this django-csvimport package](https://github.com/edcrewe/django-csvimport).  Now I want to override the default values in the Admin area form.  I found the [code here](https://github.com/edcrewe/django-csvimport/blob/master/csvimport/models.py), which defines the models, and contains the current default text:

```
class CSVImport(models.Model):
    """ Logging model for importing files """
    model_choice = []
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  default='csvimport.Item',
                                  help_text='Please specify the app_label.model_name',
                                  choices=get_models())
    field_list = models.TextField(blank=True,
                                  help_text='''Enter list of fields in order only if
                                     you dont have a header row with matching field names, eg.
                                     "column1=shared_code,column2=org(Organisation|name)"''')
    upload_file = models.FileField(upload_to='csv', storage=fs)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    encoding = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    upload_method = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50,
                                     default='manual', choices=CHOICES)
    error_log = models.TextField(help_text='Each line is an import error')
    import_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    import_user = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='anonymous',
                                   help_text='User id as text', blank=True)

    def error_log_html(self):
        return re.sub('\n', '<br/>', self.error_log)
    error_log_html.allow_tags = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.upload_file.name
```

So for example I would like override the `model_name` field default `csvimport.Item` with something else.  I am a bit at a loss how to override this as I do not have an app folder for csvimport, as its a 3rd part installation.  It will be my first time overriding a 3rd party installed app model.

Now that I look into it a bit more, not sure if I should override this model or perhaps better the `ModelAdmin` class of the `admin.py` file?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the best way to go is to create a new app in your django project. There you can import the above CSVImport class in its models.py, which you can then subclass and use as such. In that case you can leave the django-csvimport package untouched.

Comment: subclassing won't work here i saw the code and it only knows to import its own model not any other.

Answer (score 2):

```
"""Your admin.py"""

from csvimport.models import CSVImport
from csvimport.admin import CSVImportAdmin

class MyCSVImportAdmin(CSVImportAdmin):
    """Override some of the form's field properties:
       clean, creation_counter, default_error_messages, 
       default_validators, disabled, empty_value, empty_values .. etc
    """

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyCSVImportAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields["model_name"].initial = 'What you want'
        form.base_fields["model_name"].help_text = 'Please customize the fields however you like'
        return form

admin.site.unregister(CSVImport)
admin.site.register(CSVImport, MyCSVImportAdmin)
```

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to customize as above without adding some bespoke means to do so.

Comment: Sorry, you're working with a noob here, but all my `admin.py` files are inside other apps.  Thats kind of my issue, after installing the csvimporter, I look at my project, and can't see which file to edit, or if I need to create a new file.  Csv Import shows up in the admin section, and I never needed to code `admin.site.register(CSVImport)` in any admin file, so in which admin file would I use your above code?

Comment: If you havent got an app at all. Then you need to create a django app and add the above as an admin.py file to it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/
the example polls app has an admin.py

Comment: So basically the core django manage command startapp myapp creates an app with an admin file. You can copy the csvimport settings to that and run your app with any customisation to csvimport and any other custom things you might want, e.g. a home page!

Comment: Ha, sorry of course I have "an app", which i think is called a "project" in django.  Inside my project i have all my functionality organised into different apps,  using the `startapp` command, these are called apps.  After adding your csvimport to my project, it works like another app, ie with its own section in the admin panel.  I was refering that I have no app folder, because I didn't actually do `startapp` for csvimporter, it was just installed by adding the dependencies and adding `csvimport.app.CSVImportConf` to the settings.py file in the main app folder.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the whole code and `django-csvimport` package does not provide you the functionality to override anything from their code so its not possible to override without copying app to your project. Below is an example of another app `django-oauth-toolkit` which uses a user settings param to provide the functionality of modifications.

```
USER_SETTINGS = getattr(settings, "OAUTH2_PROVIDER", None)
```

Now the solution would be only to copy the app and then modify the app for your own usage.